# Container startup failed for image testcontainers/ryuk:0.5.1

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, testcontainers

I am getting this error while trying to build an image for my java app in Azure Devops' Private hosted agent, that agent is working as a Docker task in AWS.

`Container startup failed for image testcontainers/ryuk:0.5.1`

my POM looks like -

```
      <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
      <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
      <version>1.18.3</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this error ?

Answer (score 1):

As a fix according to comments to this [ticket-7082](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/7082).

You have to set

```
ryuk.container.privileged=true
```

In `.testcontainers.properties`. More details about how to set `Custom configuration` you can check [Custom configuration](https://java.testcontainers.org/features/configuration/) part of documentation.

Comment: Saved me tons of time and several times, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I'm using testcontainers with rest-assured, what solved for me was to put the rest-assured dependency above all other tests dependencies.

This is my pom.xml(the tests part) with the tests

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-testcontainers</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```